# how to sort by levels in graphviz

Tags: graphviz

I want to separate the rectangles like this

[image]

or (3 items per line)

[image]

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: digraph {

    
    a->b;
    b->c;
    d -> c[dir=back];
    e -> f;
    
    {rank=source; a; b};
    {rank=same; d; c};
    {rank=same; d; c};
    {rank=same; e;

}

Answer (score 2):

You were quite close.  Most of the changes are just for (my) clarity. `rank=same` and `dir=back`

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72449201/how-to-sort-by-levels-in-graphviz
digraph {
  {rank=same; a -> b -> c}
  {rank=same; edge [dir=back]   f -> e -> d }
  {rank=same; g -> h -> i}
  {rank=same; edge [dir=back]   l -> k -> j }
  c -> d
  f -> g
  i->j
}
```

Giving:
[image]